# Homotopical factorization of maps that are zero in homology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a cellular map between CW-complexes of dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively such that the induced maps in homology are zero after a while (i.e. $H_i(f) = 0$ for some $k$, $n\geq k>0$).

- Is it true that, up to homotopy, $f$ factors through a subcomplex $X \subseteq N$ of dimension $k$?
- If not, is there a way to classify "geometrically" these maps?

In particular, I was trying to study the set of maps up to pointed homotopy $\left[T^n, S^2\right]_*$ ($T^n$ is the $n$-fold torus, i.e. $S^1\times S^1 \dots \times S^1$), so I would love to have some results for this very specific case if the question is too broad.

Are there good references on the topic?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about exactly what you are looking for. You get an affirmative answer to your question for any map by letting $k=m=\dim M$. On the other hand, there are plenty of integers $m>n$ for which there are nontrivial maps $S^m\rightarrow S^n$ that induce zero on all homology groups.

Comment: Very fair point, you are absolutely right. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it right away. I generalized my original problem too much, but this sanity check is still very useful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ between finite-dimensional CW complexes $M,N$ you can always take $k=\dim N$ to get a facorisation of $f$ though a $k$-dimensional subcomplex of $N$. In general $f$ can be homotoped to a cellular map, so if $\dim M<\dim N$ then this improves after letting $k=\dim M$ and factoring $f$ through the $k$-skeleton of $N$.

However while these trivial factorisations always exists, there is in general no way to minimise the value of $k$ with respect to the action of $f$ on homology.

For instance, if $n>1$, then there are infinitely many integers $m>n$ for which there is a non-homotopically trivial map $f:S^m\rightarrow S^n$. For dimensional reasons this map induces $0$ on $\widetilde H_*$. The fact that $f$ is not null-homotopic, however, means that it does no factor through the zero-skeleton of $S^n$, or in fact the $k$-skeleton for any $k<n$.

For an explicit example of such a map we can take the Hopf map $\eta:S^3\rightarrow S^2$. Moreover we can make this relevant to the problem at hand by considering the map $f:T^3\rightarrow S^2$ which is given by the composition
$$f:T^3\rightarrow S^3\xrightarrow\eta S^2,$$
where the first map collapses the $2$-skeleton of $T^3$ to a point. It is a consequence of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998451/does-f-1g%e2%89%83f-2g-imply-f-1%e2%89%83f-2/3999846#3999846) that $f$ is not null-homotopic. Yet $f$ induces $0$ on $H_2T^3$ because $\eta$ does. This example generalises to any $n\geq 3$ for which there is a non-trivial map $S^n\rightarrow S^2$.